# publishing windows application for per-machine use

Tags: windows, visual-studio, security, publishing

I have two questions, I am pretty much inexperienced in this kind of stuffs and this is my first time I want to do this so I appreciate if you give me a clean guideline and if it's possible without too many jargons.

1. what is the simplest way to make an installation setup for my app.exe file? I saw some answers about **WIX**, is it simple?

2.This is my important issue, how can I make sure the client can only installs this application on only one system. He can buy one and installs on his own computer but not any other system after that.

I would appreciate If you help me with some links to easy to follow guides, I am a total newbie in this Area and this is my first time using windows and visual studio so I am not very familiar with them.

Comment: This is pretty wide open.  There are many tools for building installers, and they all compete on "simplicity," so question 1 boils down to asking for a recommendation.  Question 2 boils down to a recommendation for a DRM (digital rights management) solution.

Comment: thank you for introducing me to DRM. I'll search around that keyword then.